# Custom title bar issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I set a custom title bar as example  http://coderzheaven.com/2011/06/custom-title-bar-in-android/ , every thing works fine but still blue frame appear from original title . The only thing I added is to set the background color to custom title as (android:background="#EECBAD"). How can I remove this blue frame?

###custom_title.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:background="#EECBAD"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <ImageView
     android:layout_width="40dip" 
     android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
     android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
     android:layout_height="40dip" /> 
    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:id="@+id/tv" 
    android:text="ELNABIH"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:textColor="@drawable/red"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

#### java.class

```
      package com.test.list;
    import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.Window;
     import android.widget.TextView;
     public class Tttt extends Activity {  
     @Override 
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
           Boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature
           (Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
           setContentView(R.layout.main);  
           if (customTitleSupported) { 
               getWindow().setFeatureInt
           (Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title); 
               TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);  
               tv.setText("name");  


             }
           }
         }
```

Comment: Please add the code of your layout, where you have modified the background

Comment: Could you supply the contents of your main layout file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother, I think this [link](http://www.anddev.org/resources/file/821) would help you for sure. I think you'll have to define styles and themes in xml too.

Please create **styles.xml & themes.xml** in values folder folder under **res**. Write the following code :

**Code for styles.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resources> <style name="WindowTitleBackground" parent="android:Theme"> 
    <item   name="android:background">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    </style>
    </resources>
```

**Code for themes.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">54px</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>                 
    </style>
    </resources>
```

and insert this in your manifest - `android:theme="@style/MyTheme"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to override "android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle".

Answer (score 1):

If you set the background color for *tv* `TextView`, it's because it also has some right and left padding, beside being set to `wrap_content`:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
```

You can remove those lines, or try to set the background color for the parent, *RelativeLayout01*

Comment: already i set background color to relative layout not the textview , update above

Comment: Have you also tried to remove the 2 margin attributes? I am sure the styling solution works fine, but in my opinion it was not really necessary for this case.

Answer (score 1):

put on style.xml:

```
<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">@color/LightFacebook</item>
    </style>
```

on @color/LightFacebook use u custom color.

Answer (score 0):

You should hide the default title first. You should declare that in AndroidManifest.xml for the activity or set the window params in the java code.

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: please can you check update above i did it as custom layout not as style or theme , thanks